# Implement caching framework(ehcache) to cache the Lookupcode and Location dropdown values during the server startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, caching

I want to load both the LookupCode and Location data from database
into cache memory using Spring ehCache when the application starts i.e
when the server starts before any other method is called. In future
few more dropdowns will be added. So there should be a common method
to cache whatever datas comes in based on the criteria of the dropdown
data.

There is a Entity, Repository and Service already written for
Lookupcode and Location

I have written the below for implementing caching framework:

**ehcache.xml**

`<cache name= "LookupCodeRepository.getDropdownValues"/> <cache name= "LocationRepository.getDropdownValues"/>`

**application.properties**

```
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache = false
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache = false
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class =
 org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.provider_class =
 org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries = true
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region_prefix =
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path
 = ehcache.xml spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache
```

and using hibernate-ehcache jar in **pom.xml**

**WebConfig.java**

```
 @Configuration public class WebConfig implements
 ServletContextInitializer{
 
 @Autowired CustomCache cache;
 
 @Override public void onStartup ( ServletContext servletContext)
 throws ServletException{
 
 cache.loadCache();
 
 }
```

**CustomCache.java**

```
 public class CustomCache {
 
 @Autowired private LookupCodeService lkupSer;
 
 @Autowired private LocationService locSer;
 
 public void loadCache(){
 
 List<LookupCode> lkup = lkupServ.getDropdownValues();
 
 List<Location> locat = locSer.getDropdownValues();
 }
```

So here in `loadCache()` method instead of calling each individual
service it should be like, automatic. Whatever service is created
it should automatically be cached. So there should be a common method
to     cache whatever datas comes in based on the criteria of the
dropdown data.

How to implement that?

Comment: Please properly format the question (code should be code etc.) don't use quoting for everything. Currently, your question is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

The services you want to work with have a common method. Define an interface for that method:

```
   interface ProvidesDropdownValues<T> { 
     List<T> getDropdownValues(); 
   }
```

Now you can do:

```
    class DropdownValuesService {
      @Autowired ApplicationContext context;
      @Cacheable List getDropdownValues(String beanName) {
        ProvidesDropdownValues<?> bean = ((ProvidesDropdownValues) context.getBean(beanName));
        return bean.getDropdownValues();
      }
    }
```

If your services don't have bean names you could work with class names instead.

For load on startup you could do:

```
  class StartupWarmupService {
    @Autowired ApplicationContext context;
    @Autowired DropdownValuesService dropDowns;
    @PostConstruct void startup() {
      for (String n : context.getBeanNamesForType(ProvidesDropdownValues.class)) {
        dropDowns.getDropdownValues(n);
      }
    }
  }
```

I suggest that the load code only runs in the production application. That is why it makes sense to keep it separate from the general caching logic. For testing a single service you don't want to load everything. Startup times for developers should be fast.

Disclaimer: I am not a heavy Spring user, so details may be wrong but the basic approach should work out.